# String algorithms where runtime doesn't depend on data contents

Tags: string, language-agnostic

There is classic algorithm to check whether two same length strings are equal while preventing a timing attack.

```
foldl bitwiseOr 0 (zipWith bitwiseXor firstString secondString) == 0
```

In such a scenario, a malicious user gets the machine to compare a hidden, secret string with an input string, and report whether they're the same. For example, consider a brute-force password attack where the passwords are encrypted but not hashed. It takes longer to determine that the passwords don't match if more initial characters match, and if the user can measure the effect, they can progressively guess the password from beginning to end.

But is there any common algorithm that answers which string is greater, or if they're equal, resisting such an attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to adjust any common algorithm with early exit to satisfy the requirement. But it's tricky, because the CPU will execute code faster if it can figure out that you're just spinning uselessly.

The safest design is to eliminate all branches inside the loop. No `if`, `&&`, or `||` allowed, just bitwise operators.

For a collating `strcmp`, we want to remember the first difference between the strings and which side was greater. So the algorithm naturally does completely different things depending on whether the difference has been found or not. We can simulate a branch using a bit mask.

```c
int obscure_strcmp( char const *l, char const *r ) {
    int result = 0;

    do {
        // compute result in case we need it
        int diff = * r - * l; // positive if l < r, negative if r < l
        int diff_pos = diff > 0; // 1 if l < r
        int diff_neg = - ( diff < 0 ); // -1 if r < l

        // assign result if it was still zero
        unsigned mask = - ( result == 0u ); // all 1's if waiting for a diff
        result |= ( diff_pos | diff_neg ) & mask;

    } while ( * l ++ && * r ++ );
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, maybe constant time is not a good term. I actually mean not same time for every strings but an algorithm that works in same time for each strings of same length. I saw this term in several places, for example in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Heimdal/Heimdal-172.18/lib/roken/ct.c

Comment: @FedorGogolev You need to read about "Big O notation." It's a fundamental, essential concept in computer science and should be taught in any introductory course. Unfortunately, Wikipedia's article doesn't seem very accessibly written and I don't have a good resource on hand. As for the linked source, the comment which mentions "constant time" is in poor English and the terminology is totally unorthodox.

Comment: Yes, I know what you about. I will update the question with you remarks.

Comment: @FedorGogolev Sorry to be grumpy… I'm trying to come up with a suitable algorithm. In the meantime, here's an outline of the basic approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you final algorithm. I will accept your answer after finally realize it. I actually not so close with the language which it implemented whatever it is ^^

Comment: @FedorGogolev Thanks for the interesting problem. By the way, now I see my algorithm reveals the length of the password by exiting after reaching the end of the shorter string. You should pad the string to the given length `n` as done by the Apple code you linked.